# Python mechanize to login to account - form not submitting

Tags: python, forms, authentication, mechanize

I am trying to login to my bank website using Python and mechanize.

https://chaseonline.chase.com/Logon.aspx

I have looked at all the previous posted but still can't login. I'm thinking it may have to do with the way I am submitting my form. The HTML for the submit button is:

```
<input type="image" id="logon"
src="https://chaseonline.chase.com/images/logon.gif" onclick="return
check_all_fields_logon_RSA_Auth(document.getElementById('UserID'),
document.getElementById('Password'));" width="58" height="21" border="0"
title="Log On" tabindex="7">
```

Here is the script I'm using:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2 
import cookielib
from time import sleep

chase_url = 'https://chaseonline.chase.com/Logon.aspx'

# Browser 
br = mechanize.Browser() 

# Enable cookie support for urllib2 
cookiejar = cookielib.LWPCookieJar() 
br.set_cookiejar( cookiejar ) 

# Broser options 
br.set_handle_equiv( True ) 
br.set_handle_gzip( True ) 
br.set_handle_redirect( True ) 
br.set_handle_referer( True ) 
br.set_handle_robots( False ) 

# Refresh handle 
br.set_handle_refresh( mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time = 1 ) 

br.addheaders = [ ( 'User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1' ) ] 

# authenticate 
br.open(chase_url) 
br.select_form( nr=0 ) 

br.form['UserID'] = 'joe1234'
br.form['Password'] = '123456'
br.submit() 

print "Success!\n"

sleep(10)

print br.title()
```

If the login worked, then the page should be "Chase Online - My Account"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar but with ESPN a few months ago. Mechanize gave me problems, then someone gave me the answer.

The answer is selenium.
https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/getting-started.html

Otherwise, what exactly is going wrong when you run your script? Does it produce an error? What does the error say?

Comment: no, there is no error. it just doesn't go to the page that is after the form submission. I check this with: `print br.title()`